# Reading Image from j2me to c++

Tags: java, c++, c, sockets, java-me

I am learning c++ in order to create a little application which displays image stream. The images are coming from a j2me device which aren't stored as a file (so I just have the bytes).

I am thinking I need to send the size of the image as an int first so then the client knows how much to read for that particular image in the stream.

My problem is the size is always way too big - not the size of the image when I initially just try to read the size (I send this length in java server in a socket.write(int) and have tried dataoutputstream.writeInt). I will post some code as it's probably pretty simple.

Why is the size different to what I send?

```
 ssize_t
 readLine(int fd, char *buffer, size_t n)
 {
 ssize_t numRead, tt;                    /* # of bytes fetched by last read() */
 size_t totRead;                     /* Total bytes read so far */
 char *buf;
 char ch;

 if (n <= 0 || buffer == NULL) {

     return -1;
 }

 buf = buffer;                       /* No pointer arithmetic on "void *" */

 totRead = 0;
 for (;;) {
     numRead = read(fd, &ch, 1);
     tt += numRead;
     if (numRead == -1) {

             return -1;              /* Some other error */

     } else if (numRead == 0) {      /* EOF */
         if (totRead == 0)           /* No bytes read; return 0 */
             return 0;
         else                        /* Some bytes read; add '\0' */
             break;

     } else {                        /* 'numRead' must be 1 if we get here */
         if (totRead < n - 1) {      /* Discard > (n - 1) bytes */
             totRead++;
             *buf++ = ch;
         }

         if (ch == '\n')
             break;
     }
 }

 printf("read line %s ", buf);
 fflush(stdout);
 int test = (int)buf;
 printf("read line int %i ", tt);
  fflush(stdout);
 *buf = '\0';
 return totRead;
```

}

Comment: Please compile with all warnings and debugging information (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g` on Linux), and learn to use the debugger (e.g. `gdb` on Linux) and memory leak-finding tools (e.g. `valgrind` on Linux). Also tell us on which operating system you are developing then running your application.

Comment: Do you mean debugger as opposed to printing to console? The os is playbook qnx platform.

Comment: I have trying to send an int for nearly 24 hours - please if someone can just tell me what stupid thing I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

`WBXML` defines a platform independent way to write `int` values: [Multy-byte integers](http://www.w3.org/TR/wbxml/#_Toc443384895).

> A multi-byte integer consists of a series of octets, where the most significant bit is the continuation flag and the remaining seven bits are a scalar value. The continuation flag indicates that an octet is not the end of the multi-byte sequence. A single integer value is encoded into a sequence of N octets. The first N-1 octets have the continuation flag set to a value of one (1). The final octet in the series has a continuation flag value of zero (0).
>   The remaining seven bits in each octet are encoded in a big-endian order, eg, most significant bit first. The octets are arranged in a big-endian order, eg, the most significant seven bits are transmitted first. In the situation where the initial octet has less than seven bits of value, all unused bits must be set to zero (0).
>   For example, the integer value 0xA0 would be encoded with the two-byte sequence 0x81 0x20. The integer value 0x60 would be encoded with the one-byte sequence 0x60.

I did it for Java ME and Bada but it is pretty straightforward to implement in any language.

Answer (score 0):

Your reading code handles text files, it works one char after the other, it checks for newlines, etc.
The image ("so i just have the bytes") seem to be binary data. When you interpret binary data as text, you get all sorts of random errors. These binary data may include for example a "\n", when the value of a pixel happen to be 13. It may also include "\0", which will end the string before the real end.

When store the size first, you send it as int, which is represent with 4 bytes. When you read it as 4 separate characters, you get some garbage.
You need also beware of order/endian of bytes. java uses "network order", on x86, C may read it just the other way around.

You are using the old C standard lib. It may be easier to use the C++ iostreams.